# Work with Custom Attributes on my C# POCO class

Tags: c#, asp.net, poco

In my project I have one class called `Area` like below.
The property "`CodArea`" I want to put one custom attribute like `[NaoSelecionarAttr(true)]`.
This is working fine but when I create one instance of the class I can not get this custom attribute. Something like this:

```
Area areaPoco = new Area();
areaPoco.CodArea.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NaoSelecionarAttr),true).ToList();

[Serializable]
public class Area
{
    #region Private Members     
    private decimal _numChave;
    private string _codArea;

    public Area()
    {
        _numChave = 0;
        _codArea = null;
    }

    public Area(decimal  pNumChave,     string pCodArea)
    {
        NumChave = pNumChave;
        CodArea = pCodArea;
    }
    public virtual decimal NumChave
    { get { return _numChave;}
      set { _numChave = value;}
    }

    [NaoSelecionarAttr(true)]
    public virtual string CodArea
    { 
            get {   return _codArea; }
            set   { _codArea = value;}
    }
}

public class NaoSelecionarAttr : Attribute
{
    public bool NaoSelecionar { get; set; }
    public NaoSelecionarAttr(bool pSim) { this.NaoSelecionar = pSim; }
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: `areaPoco.CodArea..GetCustomAttributes()`.  Did you try something that does compile?

Comment: I wrote it here wrong. My code is copiling.

Comment: Please update your code Fabio so that we know what you are trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

The first problem in the code is that you are calling the default constructor on `Area`, which initializes `_codArea` to null. And then you try to call `GetType` on it, which fails with a `NullReferenceException`, as expected.

The second problem is that you want an attribute of a property of a class. So you must inspect (or reflect) the class, not the property. You see, when you write `areaPoco.CodArea...` the compiler resolves it to the result of your `get` expression, in this case, the field `_codArea`. By calling `GetType()` on `_codArea`, what you retrieve is a `String` type, not your `Area` type. I know this may seem confusing at first, but properties aren't types, so you can't reflect on them.

What you should do, then, is:

```
Area areaPoco = new Area();
NaoSelecionarAttr attr = (NaoSelecionarAttr) (areaPoco.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "CodArea").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NaoSelecionarAttr), true).Single());
bool naoSelecionar = attr.NaoSelecionar;
```

---

If I may, I want to give you some tips as well:

- Your notation for the non-default constructor seems reminiscent of C/C++. There usually isn't a good reason to stick a "p" prefix in the parameters.
- Instead of NaoSelecionar, which is a negative property, I recommend you work with "Selecionar". The deal is that you can easily confuse a negative sentence with its correspondent positive one. A month from now you will ask, "ok, the parameter is false, so should I select or not this property?". False usually means NOT, so, your default interpretation would be not to select something when the property is false.
- Your default constructor is initializing a property to `null`. Just as I described above, this can result in bugs. Either initialize it to a default value (`string.Empty`), or remove the default constructor and use only the one that requires the user to provide a value to string. And **validate** those parameters as well -- the user might provide again a `null` to the string. (An object should be valid when first constructed)
- One final tip. Your `NaoSelecionar` attribute gets a boolean parameter. The last bullet was exactly about that -- you can confuse whether having a true property for your attribute means "não" or "sim". Well, why don't you simply remove the parameter and **then** work with a negative parameter? There's no need to pass **true** or **false** to `NaoSelecionar`, since all you need to do is iterate through your class and find which properties have this attribute applied to them.

Comment: In fact, i don´t know the right way to do this, but I know what I want :) . For instance: Area areaPoco = new Area(); if (areaPoco.CodArea.NaoSelecionar == true) do something

Comment: @Fabio, I've added enough information so you can achieve what you want.

Comment: @Fabio, "sem problemas"! At your service.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `areaPoco.CodArea.GetType()`? I think you should use `areaPoco.GetType()`. Because your custom attribute belongs to the Area class, not to the string.

Comment: In fact, i don´t know the right way to do this, but I know what I want :) . For instance: Area areaPoco = new Area(); if (areaPoco.CodArea.NaoSelecionar == true) do something